# pthread_getschedparam No Matching Function Call

Tags: c++, pthreads

I'm a little confused why the following code is generating an error "No matching function to call 'pthread_getschedparam'" when I try to build it with XCode:

```
#if MACRO_OSX_PLATFORM()
#include <pthread.h>
#endif
...
struct sched_param sp = {0};
pthread_getschedparam(pthread_self(), SCHED_OTHER, &sp);
return sp.sched_priority;
```

Any thoughts? Did I miss something essential? By the way, the macro that checks for OSX platform works, 100 percent.

Comment: `#if MACRO_OSX_PLATFORM()` looks a bit strange, do you mean `#if MACRO_OSX_PLATFORM`? What happens if pthread.h is included without conditions?

Comment: Thanks. Same error without conditional include. The brackets in the macro call are ok, it's used in this way throughout the whole project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to `pthread_getschedparam` is a pointer to an int.  You have instead passed in an int constant (SCHED_OTHER).

From the [OS X docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/pthread_setschedparam.3.html):

`int
pthread_getschedparam(pthread_t thread, int *restrict policy, struct sched_param *restrict param);`

Emphasis added.  You mean something like this:

```
int dummy; // We don't care what current policy is
struct sched_param sp = {0};
pthread_getschedparam(pthread_self(), &dummy, &sp);
return sp.sched_priority;
```

Comment: Oh, ok. I don't fully understand the SCHED_OTHER, I know it's the default scheduling policy like FIFO, Round Robin and such. But I don't see I would create a pointer to SCHED_OTHER to pass as a function argument.

Comment: @DenverCoder21, you'd pass SCHED_OTHER to `pthread_*set*schedparam` to fix the scheduling policy.  You pass in a pointer to an int to *query* the current sched policy.  Answer updated.

Comment: Aah, now I get it. Thank you!